# splash screen should ended in 3 sec and login activity should start after that

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-fragments, android-listview

please some one can help me for that if you can

```
public class SpalshScreenActivity extends Activity {

    public void onAttachedToWindow() {

        super.onAttachedToWindow();

                Window window = getWindow();
                window.setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        StartAnimations();
    }
    private void StartAnimations() {
        Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.alpha);
        anim.reset();
        LinearLayout l=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lin_lay);
        l.clearAnimation();
        l.startAnimation(anim);
        anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.translate);
        anim.reset();
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.logo);
        iv.clearAnimation();
        iv.startAnimation(anim);
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: i have to end splash screen activity in 3 sec

Comment: That isn't a question; it's a requirement. StackOverflow is not a coder-for-hire site.

Comment: i am stack here i am asking for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you have two options the first one is to use timer

```
               Timer timer= new Timer();
            timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Intent i = new Intent(SplashActivity.this,yourloginActivity.class);
                           startActivity(i);

                    finish();
                }
            }, 3000);
```

or you can move to the login screen after finishing the animation by setting the animation duration to 3000 as the code below

```
                      anim.setDuration(3000);
                  anim.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            finish();
            Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this,
                    yourLoginActivity.class);

            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code. Declare your required time in splashTime

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
            SplashScreen.this.startActivity(intent);
            SplashScreen.this.finish();
        }
    }, splashTime);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
anim.setDuration(3000);
```

And

```
Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

in `onAnimationEnd` in your [animation listener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.AnimationListener.html). Hope that helps.